# Using excel column headers for Shiny's 'custom-input-control' example

Tags: shiny

I'm trying to pass in a list of header names from a user uploaded excel sheet as the select options to the left hand select box, for the Custom-Input-Control code as shown at 
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/custom-input-control.html

The select box just shows the text dataset.. instead of all the headers.

My current code is

```
ui.r:

library(shiny)
source("chooser.R")

shinyUI(fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("Linear Regression"),

  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Upload",
             # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
             sidebarLayout(
               wellPanel(
                 fileInput(
                   'file1',
                   'Choose XLSX File',
                   accept = c('sheetName', 'header'),
                   multiple = FALSE
                 )
               )
               ,
               mainPanel(tableOutput('contents'))

             )),
    tabPanel("Choose",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 chooserInput("mychooser", "Available Rows", "Chosen Rows",
                                unlist(strsplit("dataset", split=","))  , c(), size = 10, multiple = TRUE
                 ),
                 verbatimTextOutput("selection") 

                ) ,
               mainPanel("")

             ))

  ))))



server.r:

library(shiny)
require(gdata)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


    output$contents <- renderTable({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.xls(inFile$datapath,1)

  })

  output$dataset<-reactive({ 
    inFile <- input$file1 

   colnames(read.xls(inFile$datapath, 1))
  })

  output$selection <- renderPrint(
    input$mychooser
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix it using some javascript

```
server.r

  observe({
    input$file1
    inFile <- input$file1 
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    colnameslist =  colnames(read.xls(inFile$datapath, 1))
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "myCallbackHandler", colnameslist)
  })

message.js

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("myCallbackHandler",
        function(colnameslist) {
         // alert(colnameslist);
          var select = document.getElementsByClassName("left")[0];
          var partsOfStr = JSON.stringify(colnameslist).split(',');
           for (var i = 0; i<=partsOfStr.length; i++){
              var opt = document.createElement("option");
              opt.value = partsOfStr[i];
              opt.innerHTML = partsOfStr[i];
              select.appendChild(opt);
          }
        });
```